# TikZ, geometry: Gap over tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, geometry

I choose `width=18cm, height=26cm` in geometry.sty. 
If I set the origin at the `page center` and positionate a node at `(-0.5\textwidth, 0.5\textheight)` I get a gap over the tikzpicture.

How to get rid of that gap.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe=true, width=18cm, height=26cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  shift={(current page.center)},
  overlay,remember picture,
  nodes={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}
]
  \node[
    anchor=north west, 
    draw, red, 
    minimum width=1.0\textwidth,text width=1.0\textwidth-2mm,
    minimum height=6cm,text depth=6cm-4mm,
    align=left, 
  ] at (-0.5\textwidth, 0.5\textheight) (Textbox) {ABC};

  % Help
  \node[blue] at (0,0) {x};
  \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (0,0.5\textheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the showframe option shows a wrong frame because if you draw `\draw[blue] (0,0)--(0,-0.5\textheight);`, the line overpasses bottom text border by the same amount which is missing to reach top border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation

You shift the tikz coordinates by paper size (`shift={(current page.center)}`), but put the node relative to text area size (`at (-0.5\textwidth, 0.5\textheight)`).

- Since the left and right margin between paper size and text area size is the same (in your example), node `Textbox` is both horizontally centered relative to paper and text area.
- Since the upper and lower margin between that two sizes are different, node `Textbox` is not vertically centered relative to text area.

#### Solution

Package `tikzpagenodes` provides extra nodes having the size of text area, marginpar area, and header and footer area. The new node `current page text area` is your help:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe=true, width=18cm, height=26cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % replace node "current page"
  shift={(current page text area.center)},
  overlay,remember picture,
  nodes={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}
]
  \node[
    anchor=north west, 
    draw, red, 
    minimum width=1.0\textwidth,text width=1.0\textwidth-2mm,
    minimum height=6cm,text depth=6cm-4mm,
    align=left, 
  ] at (-0.5\textwidth, 0.5\textheight) (Textbox) {ABC};

  % Help
  \node[blue] at (0,0) {x};
  \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (0,0.5\textheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aha, tikzpagenodes.sty, I understand. Very good.